# Display Facebook connect module in the header

Tags: php, opencart

I have installed the "Facebook Connect" extension in Opencart and it works fine, but the customer is asking me to move it on the fixed part below the header that always shows the cart total and content

WELCOME VISITOR YOU CAN LOGIN OR CREATE AN ACCOUNT
Cart: 1 item(s) - €42.3

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWsQn.jpg

So basically she wants that the "facebook connect" button is always visible on all pages.
How can I do that?

Another thing that she would like it to have the "facebook connect" on the login page,in the area for new customer, right near the the continue button

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaU8j.jpg

Comment: Can you, please, show us something you have tried for yourself or are you expecting us to give you the whole solution for free? If you are unable to do this on your own you should consider recommending your client to hire a real OpenCart Dev.

Answer (score 0):

Opencart, as you know, has only 4 positions for modules to be placed at. So you have 2 options.

One is to create a new position, eg 'top header', but this is too much work for sth as simple as that. Of course you can buy a module that does that but I think it will not do exactly what you want.

Your second option is to edit the header.tpl and the header conrtoller files. Since this is a custom theme, if there are no upgrades planned to the whole theme, I would recommend editing the tpl file directly and adding changes to the controller via vqmod. What you need is to find the code from the facebook connect extension that outputs this blue button (look in a facebook_connect.tpl, or sth similar in the default theme) together with any javascript or css rules and place this code in the appropriate place in the header.tpl of your theme. Then see if there is any code in the facebook connect extension's controller file that is necessary for the button to work. If so, first try to see if you can skip it by adding manually anything you can directly in the tpl file. Eg if there is a setting for a facebook id or sth that is loaded in the controller file just to be output in the tpl file, just put the id directly in the tpl file. The rest of the code just put it in a vqmod file to place it somewhere in the index function of the header controller.